# Events Editable But Public URL is Bad

Tags: wordpress, civievent, urls

Wordpress 5.6, CiviCRM 5.32.1, Shared server with ssh access
When I go to Events -> Dashboard and choose an event to review an existing or past event, I can edit it but when I choose the public link at the bottom of the page I get this:

https://nonprofit.org/wp-admin/admin.php?civiwp=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fevent%2Finfo&id=56&reset=1

This gives a white screen for anyone, even an admin. When I manually change it to remove wp-admin/admin.php I get this format:

https://nonprofit.org/?civiwp=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fevent%2Finfo&id=56&reset=1

Which gives me a list of old events - not the specific event.

I can edit the events. I simply can't show them publicly.
I suspect this has something to do with this post:
https://civicrm.org/blog/kcristiano/civicrm-526-and-wordpress-important-notice
However, WP was updated to 5.5 before I updated civicrm.

And of course this is different because it's adding the admin part to the URL.
If anyone has suggestions, I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.
I needed a base page.
It's fixed!